# How to find the <tr> data relevant to the clicked button within table in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is the UI 
[image]

What I want is, when user will click on any of the "Approve" or "Reject" button, I want to get the "Remarks" value of that particular row.

Here is the cshtml code I have so far

```
@model IEnumerable<HrmsMvc.Models.DataContext.LeaveRecord>

@{
    using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Approve Leave</legend>

        <div style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 10px;"overflow-scrolling: auto>

            @{
            if (Model != null)
            {
                <table>

                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Apply Date</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>From</th>
                            <th>To</th>
                            <th>Type</th>
                            <th>Reason</th>
                            <th>Status</th>
                            <th>Remarks</th>
                            <th>Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    @{
                        try
                        {
                            foreach (var leave in Model)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.ApplicationDate.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.EmployeeInfo.FullName)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.EffectiveFrom.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.EffectiveTo.Value.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.LeaveType)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.Reason)</td>
                                    <td>@Html.LabelForModel(leave.LeaveStatus)</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <input type="text" style="width: 200px;" data-text-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td style="display: block; width: 200px;">
                                        <input type="submit" style="width: 80px; height: 25px; background-color: greenyellow;" value="Approve" data-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
                                        <input type="submit" style="width: 80px; height: 25px; background-color: lightcoral;" value="Reject" data-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>    
                            }
                        }
                        catch
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            }

            }

        </div>

    </fieldset>
    }
}




@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var leaveRecordId = 0;
        var applicantEmid = "";
        var leaveType = "";
        var applicationDate = "";
        var leaveStatus = "Pending";
        var reason = "";
        var entryEmid = "";
        var entryDate = "";
        var lastUpdateEmid = "";
        var lastUpdateDate = "";
        var effectiveFrom = "";
        var effectiveTo = "";

        $(document).ready(function () {
                   // here I want to get the button and the related remarks data
            });


        });

    </script>

}
```

Each button has a data-id attribute which contains the related RecordID. I do not understand how to get this or where to start?

Comment: just try below answer it will work..

Comment: @Exception, I am using idea. However, thanks to every one for your  help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give Approve and Reject buttons class 'btn' and try below answer :

```
$(.btn).click(function(){
  var textvalue = $(this).closest('tr').find('td').eq(7).find('input[type=text]').val();
});
```

OR if you want to get `RecordID` of buttons on click then do this :

```
$(.btn).click(function(){
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simply changing 2 line of code in your CSHTML and then adding a click event for the buttons.

Since you are using input of type "Submit", whenever you click on the button it actually posts back to server and the method written for the click doesn't actually performs as you want it to perform.

So the first thing would be, replace the below code to change the 2 buttons of type submit to type button.

```
<input type="button" style="width: 80px; height: 25px; background-color: greenyellow;" value="Approve" data-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
```

Then add the following method in jquery to get the data-id as well as the Remarks text.

```
$(document).on("click", "tr input[value=Approve],input[value=Reject]", function () {
    var dataID = $(this).attr("data-id");
    var txtValue = $(this).parent().parent().find("td:nth-child(8)>input[type=text]").val();
alert("dataid:" + dataID + ",remarks:" + txtValue);
```

});

here, the **dataID** will get you the value in the "**data-id**" property and **txtValue** will get the value in the "**Remarks**" textbox of that specific row, you can simillarly find anything you want within the row.

Not sure, why the button is given as submit type, but if you really want some controller action to be called on the click then you can perform that by using jquery ajax to call the controller as below:

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ControllerName/Action',
   type: 'POST', //POST if you want to save, GET if you want to fetch data from server
   success: function(obj){
        // here comes your response after calling the server
   }    
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: In `ajax` part of your suggested solution, did you mean to add the **dataID** and **txtValue** as `parameters` in the `url`? I'm interested in passing these values to the `controller`. Can you please further elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click','.button_class', function(e){
    var id = $(this).data('id');// here is your data-id,do with it what you need
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this idea,

Use `onclick='getVal($(this).parent().parent())` Like below.

```
<input type="submit" style="width: 80px; height: 25px; background-color: greenyellow;"
 onclick='getVal($(this).parent().parent())' value="Approve" data-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
<input type="submit" style="width: 80px; height: 25px; background-color: lightcoral;" 
 onclick='getVal($(this).parent().parent())' value="Reject" data-id="@leave.LeaveRecordID" />
```

Now code is..

```
function getVal(element){// This will find the text input in that particular <tr>
   alert($(this).find('input[type=text]').val());
}
```

This will solve man..

Answer (score 0):

This Code wil get the data id and the remarks element from that row.
[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/3wuqnh97/2/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('table tbody tr td input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
      alert($(this).attr("data-id")+" "+  $(this).parent().parent().find('td:eq(7) input').val());
    });
    });
```

[JS FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gurunave/3wuqnh97/2/)